yarn unable to build due to some bootstrap issue
I'm trying to install a legacy Django-React project in my local Linux and, when running yarn build, I get this error:
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: /root_dir/.yarn/__virtual__/bootstrap-virtual-4e7f1514aa/5/.yarn/berry/cache/bootstrap-npm-5.3.3-da08e2f0fe-10c0.zip/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss.
        on line 3 of src/assets/scss/style.scss
>> @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

I'm not Node savvy and I tried to research for the error, but I haven't found anything, so I'll appreciate any help.

Try changing the import on line3 of bootstrap/scss... in your src/assets/scss/style.scss file to a more literal path relative to where this file will be used.
@import "../node_modules/boostrap/scss/bootstrap";

or
@import "boostrap/scss/bootstrap";

